# Will Apple Music work with iPod Classic and iPod Nano?

Tags: iphone, ipod, apple-music

Will I be able to sync offline Apple Music to non-internet Apple devices e.g. iPod Nano and iPod Classic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Unlike iPhone,iPad or iPod touch 5/6, iPod nano and iPod shuffle don't have Wi-Fi compatibility which means they won't be able to support Apple Music. But there are speculation saying that you can sync Apple Music tracks to iPod nono with iTunes and Apple Music Converter.

Answer (score 3):

Apple Music is not available on iPod nano and iPod shuffle.

See footnote 3: http://www.apple.com/uk/music/

Comment: I saw this same footnote, but I still wonder if offline tracks could be synced.

Comment: Yeah I am going to check

Answer (score 3):

Offline tracks obtained through apple music do not sync across to ipod.

Its a shame really, they could easily put a timer on the songs, so if the ipod is not plugged into registered device every so often, the songs will become locked.

Comment: Missing features like this tend to come down to the actual definition of "easily". :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently bought an iPod Nano, and I am very happy with it! The only downside is that Apple Music is not available for it. Which frankly is a new low for Apple, but I'm pretty sure they're gonna fix it up later. Although it might be a huge way for people to abuse the system. They could download a gazillion tracks into the iPod and never connect it to a computer again. For now Apple Music is not available in devices such as iPod Nano, iPod Classic or iPod Shuffle. Apple will find a way to find a way, but for now all we can do is... wait.

Answer (score -3):

Get AirPlay Recorder and download copies that can be transferred.

;)